# why cant I get http.request to work on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Hi,

I am working on my app.js file on node.js and I want to make a http request to get the contents from an URL so I can use it as a string.

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);

app.get('/myappt', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

let numUsers = 0;
    
var options = {
 host: 'http://example.net',
 path: '/test.txt',
 port: 80
};

callback = function(response) {
 var str = '';

 //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
   str += chunk;
 });

 //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
 response.on('end', function () {
   username = str;
 });

};

httpserver.request(options, callback).end();
 
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  let addedUser = false;

  // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
  socket.on('add user', (username) => {
    if (addedUser) return;
    
    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = username;
```

its not working. The whole app will stop working at all and the only thing I get on the console is 500 errors. What is that?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the `http://example.net` log (if it's your domain)?

Comment: its a text file with a single word (the user name) for example: john.

Comment: Please post a usable example.  What errors do you get?  When do you expect the httpserver.get call to fire?  What does that have to do with the socket.io code?

Comment: Your http callback builds a string called 'username' but then does nothing with it.  The `username` in the socket.on call shadows it inside that callback.

Comment: Thats what i would like to know. I have searched the web for similar examples but I havent found anything. I dont know what to do from there.